# Where should I store data, which should not cause rerender React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, babeljs

I'm developing a React.js app. I nearly understand which peace of data should be stored in component state, but how do I handle some of these:

1) For example in debug purposes I need to know how many times some method was called, so I'd do it following way

```
class SomeComponent extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state={...};
        let counter = 0;
    }

    someFunc = () => {this.counter++; ......}
}
```

2) Or I need to get some data from localstorage which has nothing to do with rendering

```
class SomeComponent extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state={...};
                this.headers = localStorage.getItem("Authorization") ? {headers: {"Authorization": localStorage.getItem("Authorization")}} : null;

    }

    componentDidMount(){axios.post("http:/blabla.com", payload, this.headers).then(...)}
}
```

Is it a good practice handling data this way. I can say that this way SomeComponent looses it's scalablity, for example if I want to split it into subcomponents or rewrite it into function component. Is it a good pratice keeping data as component class fields?

3) What if I want to store some static data which is only related to this component (Say backend is not ready yet and I use some hardcoded dummy array to show something on the screen). Should I init it outside the component in the same file like

```
const dummyArray=[{...},{...},{...}]

class SomeComponent extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state={...};
    }
    render(){
        let arrayToRender = this.state.arrayToRender ? this.state.arrayToRender : dummyArray
        return(
            arrayToRender.map(item=><div>....</div>)
        )
    }

        someFunc = () => {this.counter++; ......}
    }
```

or alternatively write a method which provides that dummy data

```
class SomeComponent extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state={...};
    }

    getDummyArray = () => [{...},{...},{...}];

    render(){
        let arrayToRender = this.state.arrayToRender ? this.state.arrayToRender : this.getDummyArray();
        return(
            arrayToRender.map(item=><div>....</div>)
        )
    }

        someFunc = () => {this.counter++; ......}
    }
```

Can there be any issues with babel when using `file-stored` (may be imported) data over `method-generated`?

Any advice or best practice would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) If you want to easily know how many times you are executing a function you can use [console.count](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console/count).

2) There is nothing wrong in keeping data outside of the state, I would say that it is even better, keep in the state only the data that you need for a re-render.

Regarding your example what I would do is move the axios call to a separate module and import it where you need it. The retrieval of the Authorization can be done when configuring axios or in the [axios request interceptor](https://github.com/axios/axios#interceptors), depends on what you need to do.

3) This really depends on you and the project architecture, I personally prefer to keeps static data in JSON files that I can import where I need.

I would suggest if you still don't have the backend yet for something that you need to build to just mock it (if it's an api for example you can use stuff like [json server](https://www.npmjs.com/package/json-server)) and build everything as if it is already done so once it is ready you just have to change a small piece.

There should be no issues with babel at all.